# Create a temporary compressed file

Tags: python

I need to create a temporary file to send it, I have tried :

```
# Create a temporary file --> I think it is ok (file not seen)
temporaryfile = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, dir=COMPRESSED_ROOT)

# The path to archive --> It's ok
root_dir = "something"

# Create a compressed file --> It bugs
data = open(f.write(make_archive(f.name, 'zip', root_dir))).read()

# Send the file --> Its ok
response = HttpResponse(data, mimetype='application/zip')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % unicode(downloadedassignment.name + '.zip')
return response
```

I don't know at all if it is the good approach..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to create a `NamedTemporaryFile` to use `make_archive`; all you want is a unique filename for the `make_archive` file to create.

### `.write` doesn't return a filename

To focus on that error: You are assuming that the return value of `f.write` is a filename you can open; just seek to the start of your file and read instead:

```
f.write(make_archive(f.name, 'zip', root_dir))
f.seek(0)
data = f.read()
```

Note that you'll *also* need to clean up the temporary file you created (you set `delete=False`):

```
import os
f.close()
os.unlink(f.name)
```

Alternatively, just omit the `delete` keyword to have it default to `True` again and only close your file afterwards, no need to unlink.

### That just wrote the archive filename to a new file..

You are just writing the new archive name to your temporary file. You'd be better off just reading the archive directly:

```
data = open(make_archive(f.name, 'zip', root_dir), 'rb').read()
```

Note that now your temporary file isn't being written to at all.

### Best way to do this

Avoid creating a `NamedTemporaryFile` altogether: Use [`tempfile.mkdtemp()`](http://docs.python.org/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkdtemp) instead, to generate a temporary directory in which to put your archive, then clean that up afterwards:

```
tmpdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
try:
    tmparchive = os.path.join(tmpdir, 'archive')

    root_dir = "something"

    data = open(make_archive(tmparchive, 'zip', root_dir), 'rb').read()

finally:
    shutil.rmtree(tmpdir)
```

Comment: It is nearly the perfection, I have the .zip in return but I don't know how I can delete it because I can't delete the file with `shutil.rmtree(tmpdir)` before the return (or I will have an empty file) and the temporary file doesn't destroy itself...

Comment: @Nico401: But you just read the data, so the archive file is no longer needed. Once the `read()` call is complete you no longer need the files on the disk.

Comment: What is the "root_dir" ? Is that the directory in which you want the archive to be created ?

Comment: @MichaelDeKeyser: it is whatever the OP of the question meant it to be.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I meant what does it represent for make_archive but now I get it. It's the directory which content's going to be zipped. Thanks tho.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am wondering if I can copy files from different directories into the tempdir?  How can I achieve that?  Thank you.

Comment: @Jimmy: You mean you want to combine files from different directories into the `make_archive()` call? You can't; it is a utility function in `shutil` that only walks one tree at a time. You'd have to recreate the same functionality using `zipfile` or any of the other supported archive formats. See the [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b8655be522d4/Lib/shutil.py#l417).

Answer (score 36):

I actually just needed to do something similar and I wanted to avoid file I/O entirely, if possible. Here's what I came up with:

```
import tempfile
import zipfile

with tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile() as tmp:
    with zipfile.ZipFile(tmp, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as archive:
        archive.writestr('something.txt', 'Some Content Here')

    # Reset file pointer
    tmp.seek(0)

    # Write file data to response
    return HttpResponse(tmp.read(), mimetype='application/x-zip-compressed')
```

It uses a `SpooledTemporaryFile` so it will remain in-memory, unless it exceeds the memory limits. Then, I set this tempory file as the stream for `ZipFile` to use. The filename passed to `writestr` is just the filename that the file will have inside the archive, it doesn't have anything to do with the server's filesystem. Then, I just need to rewind the file pointer (`seek(0)`) after `ZipFile` had done its thing and dump it to the response.

Comment: sth wrong there - tmp.close (from ``with`` ) is after return, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but that's necessary. The response needs to read from `tmp`, which requires the stream to still be open. `with` will clean everything up after the return call.

Comment: Python 2.6 has no `__exit__` attribute for `zipfile.ZipFile` so you can't use `with` unless you wrap it in `contextlib.closing`, see [Making Python 2.7 code run with Python 2.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268470)

Comment: `mimetype` param of `HttpResponse` changed to `content_type` since Django 1.4

Comment: this worked for me.  Important note if not using with, you need to close the zipfile before the seek on the temp

Comment: The code in this answer utilizes `SpooledTemporaryFile` in a way that makes it essentially pointless.  The ZipFile is constructed, written to memory **or a file**, then immediately read back out _in its entirety_ as a single string.  Memory exhaustion avoided for 15ns until memory gets immediately exhausted.  One might be able to utilize a WSGI response object that can stream, e.g. by assigning to [WebOb's `Response.body_file`](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/webob/en/stable/api/response.html#webob.response.Response.body_file).

Comment: I think SpooledTemporaryFile is essentially useless for another reason - per the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html the default max_size (rollover size) is zero. So, it rolls over to disk right away and the usage here is synonymous with using TemporaryFile(). This could be fixed with e.g. `SpooledTemporaryFile(max_size=1024*1024*2)` for 2Mb. (It's possible I'm misunderstanding something in the docs, but it seems like a bit of a 'gotchya').