# Making Python 2.7 code run with Python 2.6

Tags: python, python-2.7, compatibility, python-2.6

I have this simply python function that can extract a zip file (platform independent)

```
def unzip(source, target):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(source , "r") as z:
        z.extractall(target)
    print "Extracted : " + source +  " to: " + target
```

This runs fine with Python 2.7 but fails with Python 2.6:

```
AttributeError: ZipFile instance has no attribute '__exit__':
```

I found this suggestions that an upgrade is required 2.6 -> 2.7
https://bugs.launchpad.net/horizon/+bug/955994

But is it possible to port the above code to work with Python 2.6 and still keep it cross platform?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What about:

```
import contextlib

def unzip(source, target):
    with contextlib.closing(zipfile.ZipFile(source , "r")) as z:
        z.extractall(target)
    print "Extracted : " + source +  " to: " + target
```

`contextlib.closing` does exactly what the missing `__exit__` method on the `ZipFile` would be supposed to do. Namely, call the `close` method

Comment: For zipfile module context manager "with" is supported from python version 2.7.1 https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html try without "with" for older versions.

Answer (score 1):

zipfile module Changed in python version 2.7.1:

- If the file is created with mode 'a' or 'w' and then closed without
  adding any files to the archive, the appropriate ZIP structures for
  an empty archive will be written to the file.
- ZipFile is also a context manager and therefore supports the with
  statement.

I solved same problem by not using context manager "with" for python 2.6

```
 newzip = None
 try:
     newzip =  zipfile.ZipFile(_file + ".zip", "w", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
     newzip.write(_file)
 finally:
     newzip.close()
```

The with context manager protects against resource leaks, so in Python 2.6 I would at least still recommend a try/finally to close the resource.

Comment: The with context manager protects against resource leaks, so in Python 2.6 I would at least still recommend a try/finally to close the resource.