# How can I avoid: "ZipFile instance has no attribute '__exit__''" when extracting a zip file?

Tags: python, execfile, python-zipfile

The code is:

```
import sys
execfile('test.py')
```

In test.py I have:

```
import zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile('test.jar', 'r') as z:
    z.extractall("C:\testfolder")
```

This code produces:

```
AttributeError ( ZipFile instance has no attribute '__exit__' ) # edited
```

The code from "test.py" works when run from python idle.
I am running python v2.7.10

Comment: The title says `__exit__`, the error in the question says `extractall`, which one is relevant?

Comment: Does the same happen if you try to execute `test.py` directly? Also you should either add a second backslash or use `r"C:\testfolder"` to avoid `\t` being a tab character.

Answer (score 13):

I made my code on python 2.7 but when I put it on my server which use 2.6 I have this error :

`AttributeError: ZipFile instance has no attribute '__exit__'`

For solve this problems I use Sebastian's answer on this post :
[Making Python 2.7 code run with Python 2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268470/making-python-2-7-code-run-with-python-2-6/21268586#21268586)

```
import contextlib

def unzip(source, target):
    with contextlib.closing(zipfile.ZipFile(source , "r")) as z:
        z.extractall(target)
    print "Extracted : " + source +  " to: " + target
```

Like he said :

> contextlib.closing does exactly what the missing `__exit__` method on
> the ZipFile would be supposed to do. Namely, call the close method

Answer (score 0):

According to the Python documentation, [`ZipFile.extractall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall) was added in version 2.6. I expect that you'll find that you are running a different, older (pre 2.6), version of Python than that which idle is using. You can find out which version with this:

```
import sys
print sys.version
```

and the location of the running interpreter can be obtained with

```
print sys.executable
```

The title of your question supports the likelihood that an old version of Python is being executed because the `with` statement/context managers (classes with a `__exit__()` method) were not introduced until 2.6 (well 2.5 if explicitly enabled).

Comment: Just tried this under Python 3.4.1 and no strange errors. Obviously, with a different .zip file. If not a Python version issue, could it be a corrupt zip file issue? (Check with `zip -T file` from command line)

Comment: import sys
print sys.version; returns: 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:44:00) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: @ Martin Evans ; no. when running from idle I do not face any issues, thus the archive gets extracted  @nigel222. I tried with different zip file, all return the same problem

Comment: @user3438538: which interpreter were you running when you printed the version? Was it within idle, or run using the standalone interpreter? Try printing the version and `sys.executable` _within_ `test.py` then execute from idle and then from outside idle. You should see a difference. What output does `print sys.executable` produce?

Comment: [interpreter:] standard Idle which shipes with python 2.7.10. [sys.executable] in idle outputs: C:\Python27\pythonw.exe; outdside idle returns: None

Comment: @user3438538: how can it return `None`? What version is the external interpreter?

Comment: hmm. I believed I found the cause. when running "import sys
print sys.version" outside default idle I get: 2.5.4rc1 (2.5:723492dbab02, Feb 8 2013, 10:13:55) . Stil investigating.......