# GzipFile instance has no attribute '__exit__' when used in a "with:" block

Tags: python, gzip, python-2.6

I need to process a .gz file with Python.

I pass the filename into my Python script with:

```py
infile = sys.argv[1]

with gzip.open(infile, 'rb') as f:
    logfile = f.read()
```

which gives me:

```
with gzip.open(infile, 'rb') as f:
AttributeError: GzipFile instance has no attribute '__exit__'
```

If I manually gunzip my .gz file and then pass that to my Python script, all works fine.

```py
logfile = open(infile, 'r').read()
```

NB: I'm using Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Aug 18 2016, 15:13:37). I don't have the ability to update Python on this computer. How can I process a gzipped text file with Python 2.6?

Comment: 2.6.6 is a release from 2010. It's really, *really* ancient, and it's no surprise that it's well behind current.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Context manager support for the `gzip` module is [issue 3860](https://bugs.python.org/issue3860).

It was fixed in Python 3.1 alpha 1 (in the 3.x line) and 2.7 alpha 1 (in the 2.x line). It's still open in 2.6.6, which you're using here.

---

Of course, you can work around this by just not using context-manager syntax:

```
import sys, gzip

logfile = gzip.open(sys.argv[1], 'rb').read()
```

Comment: You can't use `with` syntax unless you update Python (or use a newer interpreter if there's more than one installed). You can, of course, still use gzip files; you just need to close your handles explicitly.

Comment: @Alan, ...that said, any VPS that has a software stack from 2010 is going to be full of security risks. I'd be very, *very* wary of using it.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33693625/8006144) answers highlights the use of `contextlib` to call the close method.

```
with contextlib.closing(gzip.open(inputFileName,'rb')) as openedFile:
    # processing code 
    # for line in openedFile:
    # ...
```