# How to zip huge plain files (+20GB) with python's ziplib file

Tags: python, large-files, zip

I get *DeprecationWarning: struct integer overflow masking is deprecated* error in z.write when file arrives to 4GB.

My code:

```
def compressOutputFile(outputFileName, outputPath=UXConfig.myPath):
  os.chdir(outputPath)
  z= zipfile.ZipFile(outputFileName+'.zip', 'wb',zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED,allowZip64=True)
  UXUtils.log('Writting file')
  z.write(outputFileName)
  UXUtils.log('Writting finished')
  z.close()
  tempFiles.append(outputPath+outputFileName)
```

The file isn't corrupted because I can open and see the lines.

Answer (score 1):

I never used the zipfile module but I used a `with` statement and tried it against an 8GB file and it worked (from 8GB to 44MB :o):

```
def zipItUp(file):
    with zipfile.ZipFile('zipped.zip', 'w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True) as zipped:
        zipped.write(file)
```

See if this does anything. If not, I think the only other solution I can think of is partitioning your file up and then the zip on each chunk.

**EDIT:**
If you're using Python 2.6, then consider including the contextlib module to handle the exit error as referenced in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268470/making-python-2-7-code-run-with-python-2-6/21268586#21268586).

Here would be the revised code:

```
import contextlib

def zipItUp(file):
    with contextlib.closing(zipfile.ZipFile('zipped.zip', 'w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED, allowZip64=True)) as zipped:
        zipped.write(file)
```

See if this works. Cheers!

Comment: I'm using Python 2.6 and it raises "zipfile instance has no attribute '__exit__'"

Comment: @LauraAbadAvilés I just added an edit for the 2.6 implementation. Hope it helps.

Comment: still failing. It always generate a file with 4.926.126.365 bytes that seems correct, but when I try to extract file tells me sumcontrol error. Maybe ZIpFile can't create zip files with that size.

Comment: No progression on this problem? Does `shutil` work with large zip files?